# how to get values from table cell dynamically in javascript

Tags: javascript, html-table

This is my code and i am trying to get values by onclick form a table cells dynamically.

```
let Table = document.querySelector('#recieve-info');
Table.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{     
     if(e.target && e.target.classList.contains('Save-Button')){
        let tr = document.querySelector('tr');
        console.log(tr.firstElementChild);
    }
});
```

Here is the output in console.log
[i am getting only the first value of table cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vk1mH.png)

Answer (score 2):

`.querySelector()` only returns the first matching element.

Use `.querySelectorAll()`, which will return an array of all matching elements. You'll then have to iterate through the array.

```
        let trs = document.querySelectorAll('tr'); //**** <- note "All" added
        trs.forEach(tr => console.log(tr.firstElementChild));
```

Comment: it will always print all values and isn't it better not to search through all document but use e.target instead?

Comment: @PaulineNemchak yes, and yes. I'm not saying this is the best way to do things, only explaining why that specific code isn't working. In general I would suggest using React over this style of DOM extraction.